# Get text from api response using lxml.etree as ET

Tags: python, lxml

Need to get text out of amazon response.  I think the trouble I'm having is finding the right path to the attributes, or at least telling lxml how to find them.  Ideally I'd like a list or dictionary of desired attributes for each item.  I found a thread on stackoverflow [How to use lxml to grab specific parts of an XML document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4456421/how-to-use-lxml-to-grab-specific-parts-of-an-xml-document/4468564#4468564) that I'm not getting to work, getting "NameError: name 'item' is not defined".  I tried moving the "item = {}" out of the loop resulting with an empty dictionary and None.
Also when I print t I get "Element {http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}ItemSearchResponse at 0x1032a30", not an ElementTree object, unsure is that is part of the issue.

So my question, how do I get this working and when I do, how do I loop through all 'item' in 'items' so that I'm getting desired attributes for all products returned? (or maybe a dictionary of lists would be the best solution). Here's a link to a sample xml response that I'm looking at https://www.box.com/s/qt2kr0h4nrig68u9w07j, I can provide a link to the entire response if it is helpful. Below is the python code that is getting the error, really just a copy from the thread mentioned above.  I am 'limited' to using lxml for parsing because of the modules being used.

UPDATE: Link to orginal (and unbroken) xml. https://www.box.com/s/2yb1ge6rxvmzshw4pj3f

```
    import bottlenose
    from lxml import etree
    import lxml.etree as ET
    from pprint import pprint as pp

    t = ET.fromstring(response)
    AMAZON_NS = "{http://webservices.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01}"
    TAGPOS = len(AMAZON_NS) # Find all ItemAttributes elements.
    for ia in t.iter(AMAZON_NS+'ItemAttributes'):
        item = {}
    # Iterate over all the children of the ItemAttributes node
        for elem in ia:
            # remove namespace stuff from key, remove extraneous whitepace from value
            item[elem.tag[TAGPOS:]] = elem.text.strip()
    print pp(item)
```

Comment: 1) The first two lines seem redundant in your code sample; 2) your sample XML is broken; 3) the code seems OK, I don't think it would raise `NameError`, but I can't check yet because the sample is broken :)

Comment: I tried your code on the original XML and it worked, no `NameError`.